# Restoring backup from a stolen iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am trying to restore my backup but it is asking to turn off "Find my iPhone" on the old device, which was stolen. How can I restore my backup?

Comment: What does a missing / stolen device have to do with restoring a backup onto a device you have in your hand? Are you really asking how to detach the current device from iCloud? Whether other devices are locked to iCloud doesn't affect a new device restore - just the status of the device in question matters. (basically restoring a backup **from a stolen phone** has zero hoops to jump through - restoring backup **to a stolen phone** requires you to get the owner to release the reservation).

Answer (score 1):

Well I guess this might help you : [iCloud: Remove your device from Find My iPhone](http://support.apple.com/kb/ph2702)

See :

## Remove an iOS device you no longer have

If you no longer have the iOS device because you gave it away or sold it, you need to remotely erase it before you can remove it.

1. Sign in to icloud.com/#find with your Apple ID (the one you use with iCloud). If you’re using another iCloud app, click the app’s name at the top of the iCloud.com window, then click Find My iPhone.
2. Click All Devices, then select the device.
3. Click Erase device, then enter your Apple ID password. Because the device isn’t lost, don’t enter a phone number or message.

   If the device is offline, the remote erase begins the next time it’s online. You’ll receive an email when the device is erased.
4. When the device is erased, click Remove from Account.

   All your content is erased and someone else can now activate the device.

Comment: I'm doing exactly this, however, it is still saying to switch off find my iphone!